# Can you change effects after capture on Instax Mini Evo

Tags: effect, special-effects, fujifilm-instax

I've just received my Instax Mini Evo and am getting to grips with it.

Obviously you can change film and lens effects before capturing a shot using the 2 dials on the camera, but can you change those effects 'after the fact'?

It would seem an obvious feature to me, given that these effects all seem to be purely digital, so there's no reason you can't (for example) add a digital vignette to a photo that was taken on normal mode ... but I can't figure out how to, or if it's possible at all.